# How can I open sql server 2005 database after i do changes with visual studio 2010?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

[image]I´m trying to open sql server 2005 database with sql server management studio but i can´t. I have done changes in that database with visual studio 2010. Is there any solution to open that database?[image]

Comment: what is error message?

Comment: it doesn´t show any error message but I can´t see the tables

Comment: You can open it anytime.

Comment: upload screen shot where problem is there

Comment: Seem like you deleted your table

Comment: but visual studio shows all the tables

Comment: are u using same server name and other details?

Comment: bdhi... is your DB name?

Comment: yes it is,................

Comment: from where you created tables? Management studio or visual studio?

Comment: i think maybe visual studio 2010 has changed database format to sql server 2008 format?

Comment: i have created with management

Comment: you need to create tables from management studio, it seems you have created them from visual studio.

Comment: I only have added rows from visual studio

Comment: will you please click refresh button in management studio? Its below object explorer

Comment: i have click refresh button like 100 times ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that i connect to db in local mode, selecting mdf file manually and with windows identification. I connect with server mode, with db user and it works perfectly. thanks!!

Comment: Ah yes. I've made that mistake before when express first rolled out. Good catch, @Mikelon85. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit like you've got the Visual Studio holding it open in single use mode.

If you restart your machine, and (without opening visual studio) try to look inside the database using SQL Server Management Studio, that might fix your issue.

**UPDATE:** It looks like the database has been upgraded to SQL2008 as you surmised. You can download SQL2008 express and export data from your 2008 database to a new 2005 file (you'll need to do that from SQL2008 express)

[Forum link describing same problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/01ed3b1c-6f29-4518-a3a4-e4e35decc05f).

Comment: ok, now i can see the error message. this server is compatible with 612 versions and older. My version is 665

Comment: but I still can´t see my tables

Answer (score 1):

If the database was set into single user mode like this

```
ALTER DATABASE YOUR_DB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

You can set it back to multi-user mode:

```
ALTER DATABASE YOUR_DB SET MULTI_USER
```